# Classpath for webdriver.jar in ubuntu

Tags: java, selenium, classpath

I downloaded webdriver jars from [webdriver downloads page](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=selenium-java-2.39.0.zip&can=1&q=)  and put them in my bin folder and tried to run my java test as

```
javac -cp folderpath/bin mytest.java
```

It gave me number of errors related to selenium library installations. How do I install java webdriver in ubuntu? I'm getting the errors below when compiling:

```
something.java:4: error: package org.openqa.selenium.support.ui does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
                                     ^
something.java:5: error: package org.openqa.selenium.interactions does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
                                       ^
something.java:6: error: package org.openqa.selenium.firefox does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
                                  ^
something.java:7: error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
^
something.java:8: error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
import static org.openqa.selenium.OutputType.*;
                                 ^
something.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
    public static boolean isAlertPresent(FirefoxDriver wd) {        
                                         ^
  symbol:   class FirefoxDriver
  location: class something
something.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
        FirefoxDriver wd;        
        ^
  symbol:   class FirefoxDriver
  location: class something
something.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
        wd = new FirefoxDriver();        
                 ^
  symbol:   class FirefoxDriver
  location: class something
something.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
        wd.findElement(By.linkText("Restore some mysql databases")).click();        
                       ^
  symbol:   variable By
  location: class something
something.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
        } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {            
                 ^
  symbol:   class NoAlertPresentException
  location: class something
10 errors
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are in directory where mytest.java is use the same command but add asterix to the path, `javac -cp folderpath/bin/* mytest.java`. Why do not you use IDE?

Comment: I want to finally run these tests from nodejs and update the status in my db

Comment: Trying to run from commandline and later asking nodejs to run similarly seems is what I am planning.